# How to loop inside an array with PHP

Tags: php, loops

How can I loop inside an array in PHP?

I'm working with mongodb and php and I'm trying to loop inside an array to repeat 50 times the same. Just getting in contact with mongodb.
Code:

```
$whatever->insertOne(
    ['name' => 'whatever',
     'data' => array(
          for ($i = 0 ; $i < 50 ; $i++) {
              '1' => array(
                  'date' => $date,
                  'value' => mt_rand(0,200)
               ),
          }
    ]);
```

This is the loop that I'm trying to run, but clearly is not going to work.

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 50 ; $i++) {}
```

And yes, I know I would repeat the '1' 50 times, which it doesn't make sense, but I'm just giving a change to mongodb.

Comment: You can't do this "inline" in your array definition. you could pre-build the `data` put it in a variable and define the array with `'data' => $data`

Comment: In php you can just have 1 key which is the same value.

Comment: @Kasper does any language support the same keyname for multiple keys?

Comment: You can do this using anonymous functions.

Comment: Not to my knowledge - that is kinda point less :).

Comment: You can create a array of arrays - but that also seems pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First construct the object with an empty `data`, then fill it with your loop, then submit it to mongo

```
$toSend = ['name' => 'whatever', 'data' => array()];

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 50 ; $i++) {
     $toSend['data'][] = [
         '1' => [
             'date' => $date,
             'value' => mt_rand(0,200)
         ]
     ];
}

$whatever->insertOne($toSend);
```

Anyway, let's pretend for a second that you didn't want the outer array inside `data`. That means you can't use the same key, so let's use `$i` for that.

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 50 ; $i++) {
     $toSend['data']["$i"] = [
         'date' => $date,
         'value' => mt_rand(0,200)
     ];
}
```

Comment: But his will not achieve the same result as you have nested arrays.

Comment: @MartiMarkov "the same result" is a bit hard to tell, given that OP does not show the intended result.

Comment: @MartiMarkov added a second example just in case.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca hahaha true that. :D

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That was so helpful! thank you so much!. Now, I'm trying to go further, how would yo loop inside an array inside a loop? haha take a look the code above in my question.

Comment: @A.Morales please don't add questions to your original question. Open another one and ping me here once you have. I'll now remove that new part from the original question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I've already created a new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231088/how-to-loop-inside-an-array-inside-a-loop-in-php