# How to loop inside an array inside a loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Basically, what I'm trying to do is loop inside a loop and in arrays. I have no idea how to do it (that's why I'm here) and I've been testing many things.

As it sounds very confused I write down the code how it would be, but clearly that's not correct.

***This below is what I've tried.***

```
$whatever->insertOne(
    ['name' => 'whatever',
    'data' => array(
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < 50 ; $i++) { // <-first loop
            'something' => array(
                for ($j = 0 ; $j < 50 ; $j++) { // <-second loop
                    'somevalue' => array(
                        'date' => $date,
                        'value' => mt_rand(0,200)
                    ) 
                }
            )
        }
    )

    ]);
```

Comment: Loop to create final array , don't loop inside an array.

Comment: Loop need to be outside . not inside

Comment: Also please provide exact format you want to create ? You need to create final array [like this](https://eval.in/970187)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop need to be outside to create final array. Don't add loop inside an array.

You probably need something like below:-

```
$data = ['name' => 'whatever'];

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 50 ; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0 ; $j < 50 ; $j++) {
    $data[$i]['something'][$j]=['somevalue' => array('date' => $date,'value' => mt_rand(0,200));
  }
}

$whatever->insertOne($data);
```

***Note:***- you can print your array before `insertOne()` to check that you are getting array of correct format or some more manipulation needed.Thanks

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. was helpful for me!

Comment: @A.Morales  glad to help you :):)

Comment: How could I do another `loop` for the `array` of date and value. eg 50 times repeating date and value.

Comment: current code is doing same. repeating date and value 50 times. So what you want now?

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
$data = array();
for ($j = 0 ; $j < 50 ; $j++) {
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 50 ; $i++) {
        $data[$j]['something'][$i]['date'] => $date;
        $data[$j]['something'][$i]['value'] => mt_rand(0,200);
    }          
}
$whatever->insertOne(['name' => 'whatever','data' => $data]);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. was helpful for me!

Comment: @A.Morales I'm glad to help you :-)